# What is the best way to generate html in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, ui-library

Is it a what to generate html in blocks to render in templates.

Working in other php frameworks there always some kind of html helper with in the framework but the only thing I can see is the is the UI library that it is so complex that I will be one our to add a simple field in the template.

Is it an easier way to create html ?

For example in Yii2 or Laravel to generate an html image tag you can use:

```
<?= Html::img('images/test.jpeg');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2. Simple define image tag HTML using

PHP:

```
<img
        id="captcha-reload"
        class="captcha-reload"
        src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Captcha::reload.png') ?>"
        alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Reload captcha') ?>"/>
```

HTML + Javascript (uiComponent, KnoutJs)

```
<img data-bind="{attr: {src: getUrlImage()}}"/>
```

-

```
<img class="product-image" data-role="image-element" src="<%- data.url %>" alt="<%- data.label %>"/>
```

No way to use sort code :D

Answer (score -1):

You should use layout

```
<referenceBlock name="_your_section_">
    <block class="Your\Module\Block\YourBlock" name="your_block_global_name" template="Your_Module::template_path.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

In template files you can use php code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Your\Module\Block\YourBlock')->setTemplate('Your_Module::template_path.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

If you don't wanna create block you can use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template class and template path by your theme

Or if you wanna did this html editable from admin panel you can call static block by php code:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

or xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="_your_section_">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

and use static block for that.

Comment: Hi Slava, this is how to implement blocks that I am using all the time what i am asking is an html helper from the framework. for example in Yii2 you can do <?= Html::img('images/test.jpeg');?> to generate the html image tag

Comment: That how to use blocks. Not use for define sort code create image tag.

Comment: <?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/text.jpeg'); ?> will return image url relative by theme and deploy or inside static\cms blocks\pages {{view url="images/text.jpeg"}}

Comment: Your are looking this?
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/ and 
/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/